# Writing output to a single csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to programming. May requirement will be simple for core developer.

I have 5 .log file which are log file of database. here I want to read these all files, check the error and success message in these files and write the error and success message to single csv file along with name of the file which I read.

```
import glob

file_list = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Rahul\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\PyCharmCE2021.3\\*.log')
file_out = open('error.csv', "a") #creating a csv file

for file in file_list:
    file_in = open(file, "r").readlines()  
    count = 0
    for line in file_in: # Loop every line
        if 'ERROR' in line: # Search for ERROR in line
            count += 1
            file_out.write(str(count) +"error.csv"+ "," + line + "\n")    #writing csv file
        elif 'SUCCESS' in line: # Search for SUCCESS in line
            print(line) # Print line
file_out.close()
```

I want output of file something like below to be written into single CSV file

```
Filename:test.log Error: Compilation error
Filename:test2.log Success: It is successful
```

Any help or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion. There's a neat module in the standard library called [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) that allows you to easily read several files in a row and also gives you access to the filenames, line numbers, etc. Try something like the following and see if it fits your needs:

```
import glob
import fileinput

file_list = glob.glob(...)

with fileinput.input(file_list) as fin,\
     open("error.csv", "a") as fout:
    out = "Filename: {}, Line: {}, {}: {}\n"
    write = False
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line_folded = line.casefold()
        if "error" in line_folded:
            write, var = True, "Error"
        elif "success" in line_folded:
            write, var = True, "Success"
        if write:
            fout.write(out.format(fin.filename(), fin.filelineno(), var, line))
            write = False
```

It's a bit unclear why you want to write a CSV-file: Your output doesn't look like it's in a csv-format?

Comment: Yes Output of .log file log file of database. in this log file I am reading Only Error and Success line. I run this code once in a week and identify common Error which are repeated.